# How to create a tearoff menu using GTKAda?

Tags: menu, gtk, ada

The question is self-explaining, how to create a tearoff menu using GTKAda? I can't make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added the code you have to your question it would be more descriptive.

I've written a bit of code to demonstrate the usage of the tear off menu with GTKAda, it's not so difficult, but it may be hard to find documentation about it:

```ada
function CreateFileMenu(tearOff : boolean) return Gtk_Menu is
    fileMenu : Gtk_Menu;
    newFile, loadFile, saveFile, saveAs, close : Gtk_Menu_Item;
begin
    --  Create the menu:
    Gtk_New(fileMenu);

    --  Add the tear off item to the menu if required:
    if tearOff then
        declare
           tear : Gtk_Tearoff_Menu_Item;
        begin
           Gtk_New(tear);
           Append fileMenu, tear);
           Show(tear);
        end;
    end if;

    --  Create the rest of the menu items:
    Gtk_New_With_Mnemonic(newFile, "_New");
    Gtk_New_With_Mnemonic(loadFile, "_Load");
    Gtk_New_With_Mnemonic(saveFile, "_Save");
    Gtk_New_With_Mnemonic(saveAs, "Save _as...");
    Gtk_New_With_Mnemonic(close, "_Close");

    --  Add the items to the menu:
    Add(fileMenu, newFile);
    Add(fileMenu, loadFile);
    Add(fileMenu, saveFile);
    Add(fileMenu, saveAs);
    Add(fileMenu, close);

    return fileMenu;
 end CreateFileMenu;
```

The `declare/begin/end` structure allows you to declare variables in run time.

The `boolean` parameter allows you decide if you want it to be a tear off menu when you create it. The function just creates the menu so you'd have to add it to a menu bar (for example) later.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the GtkAda reference manual [says](http://libre.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gtkada-docs/gtkada_rm/gtkada_rm/gtk-menu.html):

> All the menus in GtkAda can be "Tear off" menus, i.e you can detach them from their parent (either a menu bar or another menu) to keep them visible on the screen at all times).

So it sounds as if you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Yes, but they're not tear off menus, a tear off menu is one that can separate itself from the menu bar and remain visible all time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment though, I'll keep looking at it.